# Football fixture javascript algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an array with teams:

```
var teams = [a, b, c, d]
```

I need a function to generate all possible pair of matchs ,
for example if `a` plays with `b` then `c` plays with `d` in this format :

```
[{ team1: a, team2: b }, { team1: c, team2: d }]
```

then final result for 4 teams will be like below :

```
var matches = {
    0: [{ team1: a, team2: b }, { team1: c, team2: d }]
    1: [{ team1: b, team2: c }, { team1: a, team2: d }]
    2: [{ team1: c, team2: a }, { team1: d, team2: b }]
}
```

number of team is always an Even number and greater than 3 (4 , 6 ,8 , ...)

Comment: is there possibility number of team be a Odd number ? like 5

Comment: its very chalenging problem blow my mind too, can't understand downVote

Comment: @NozarSafari, that's not possible

Comment: People are given downvoting priviledges far too early - most don't even read the question. +1 from me

Comment: and number of teams is always 4 ? or its can be more ? like 6, 8 and ..

Comment: And a (-1) from me and a disagreement with @NicholasKyriakides -- the OP shows no decent attempt at a solution in his question at all, no evidence of having searched for a solution in the question, nothing.

Comment: What defines a "game match"?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It's a mind-bender - he's not asking you to give him a solution to a trivial problem that can be solved by reading a JS tutorial. If that were the case I'd agree with you. Stop defeating the purpose of this site by being pedantic.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Couldn't agree more, upvoting to balance things out.

Comment: This is quite a good question. However its quite unclear how the algorithm should behave on uneven numbers of teams and so on and so on

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, what kind of evidence do you need? The code is so much complex than I posted. I tried to be clear and make the question simple to get a simple answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach that iterates until every team has fought all his enemies:

```
 var teams = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
teams = teams.map(id => ({id}));
teams.forEach(team => team.enemies = teams.filter(enemy => enemy !== team));

const matches = [];

while(teams.some(team => team.enemies.length)){
 const playing = [];
 for(const team of teams){
  if(playing.includes(team)) continue;
   const enemy = team.enemies.find(enemy => !playing.includes(enemy));
   if(!enemy) continue;
   team.enemies.splice(team.enemies.indexOf(enemy),1);
   enemy.enemies.splice(enemy.enemies.indexOf(team), 1);
   //console.log(team.id, enemy.id, playing.map(t => t.id));
   playing.push(team, enemy);
 }
 if(playing.length) matches.push(playing.map(t => t.id))
}

console.log(matches);
```

Playing may be chunked into 2 teams per game

Comment: It only work with 4 teams , if you put 8 ,12 or more teams  in the  teams array , the result of matches will be wrong. It will return the matches array,  but with less player for each array in it. How you can solve this ? I think is related to splice

Answer (score 0):

I think its a general question of non repeating pairs.

```js
var teams = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

function possibleMatches(teams) {
  for (var firstTeam = 0; firstTeam < teams.length; firstTeam++) {
    for (var secondTeam = firstTeam + 1; secondTeam < teams.length; secondTeam++) {
      console.log("Your firstTeam and second Team", teams[firstTeam], teams[secondTeam])
    }
  }

}

possibleMatches(teams)
```

Comment: in your answer u get all possible matchs and its true, but its not what he need,

Comment: I did not understand could you please rephrase it

Comment: He showed you three possible arrangements... They obviously don't match your output.

Comment: Yeah as he mentioned all the possible matches and order doesnot matter.
It implies that he needs the possible combinations. Again if that is not the case , more info is needed , how only two objects are kept in each array. :)
what is required ?

Comment: The solution of @stack26 was a great help! But now, I need to put the result into `matches` object where each array may have the games without repeat teams.